# Convert recordes in database to Drupal database

Tags: c#, database, drupal, database-design, data-migration

Hi
I have news website and I want to migrate to Drupal.
please help me , How to convert ma Database to Drupal Database?

Is there any module to do this?

or

write a program?

I am C# developer.
help me to write this program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either do it writing your own script, mapping your structures to Drupal nodes and saving them, or use something like the [Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate). Just take a look at [Migration: Not Just for the Birds](http://www.archive.org/details/DrupalconDc2009-MigrationNotJustForTheBirds) for an overview (quite detailed) on how to do the latter.